# How to create a WYSIWYG like jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create my own jsfiddle funcionality.

Three textboxes with some codes, but have no idea how to make (and remake) files with their contents.

Or, is there another way to play the code, without creating files ?

```js
$('.button').on('click', function(){
// create demo.css, demo.html and demo.js   
// open a new tab and play all the code
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='txthtml'>
<div class='parent'>
<div class='title'>lorem 01</div>
<div class='title'>lorem 02</div>
<div class='title'>lorem 03</div>
</div>
</textarea>

<textarea class='txtcss'>
.parent{
background:gold;
}

.title{
margin:5px 0;
backgorund:lightgreen;
}
</textarea>

<textarea class='txtjs'>
$('.title').on('click', function(){
console.log('clicked');
});
</textarea>
<br><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: you can create function which attach to modal elements. Please clarify you question.

Comment: use the iframe technique and inject code into the iframe

Comment: @TemaniAfif iframe also needs files

Comment: no they don't .. you can use the the content as data .. here is a website I built using this technique : https://css-challenges.com/ ... I have only used CSS/HTML but you can add JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below, you can find a very simple example that you want.

For render html into your view, you can juste get the `value` from your `textarea` and paste in into your content that when you want to do

```js
const code = document.querySelector('.code');
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const render = document.querySelector('.render');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const getHTML = code.value;
  
  render.innerHTML = getHTML;
})
```

```css
.code {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<textarea class="code"></textarea>
<button class="btn">go</button>

<div class="render"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

create iframe and write the content to the iframe. [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ntx8c4z2/), not working here because not allowed to aceess iframe.

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var addJquery = $('#addJqury').is(':checked')
  var html = $('.txthtml').val(),
    css = $('.txtcss').val(),
    js = $('.txtjs').val(),
    output = '<style>' + css + '</style>' +
    html +
    '<script>' + js + '<\/script>';
  if (addJquery)
    output = '<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"><\/script>' + output;

  var iframe = window.results.document;
  
  iframe.write(output);
  iframe.close();
});
```

```css
textarea{min-height:80px;min-width:200px}
iframe{width:100%;height:100%;display:block}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="txthtml">
<div class='parent'>
<div class='title'>lorem 01</div>
<div class='title'>lorem 02</div>
<div class='title'>lorem 03</div>
</div>
</textarea>

<textarea class='txtcss'>
.parent{
background:gold;
}

.title{
margin:5px 0;
backgorund:lightgreen;
}
</textarea>

<textarea class='txtjs'>
$('.title').on('click', function(){
console.log('clicked: ' + $(this).html());
});
</textarea><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="addJqury" checked> Add Jquery?
<br><br>
<button>CLICK</button>
<hr>Results:
<hr>
<iframe name="results" src="about:blank"></iframe>
```